# data class uniinitialize by lateinit property

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mvvm, android-recyclerview

when i try to initialize data class it gives me error, kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property article_ has not been initialized. How do i resolve this error and whats way to initialize data class.

model class

```
data class Article(
    val id: Int,
    val author: String,
    val content: String,
    val description: String?)
```

MainActivity

```
class TestActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var binding: ActivityTestBinding
    lateinit var article_: List<Article>

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_test)

val mainAdapter = MainAdapter(article_)
        binding.recView.apply {
            this.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@TestActivity)
            this.adapter = mainAdapter
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ANSWER:

In `onCreate()` before this line `val mainAdapter = MainAdapter(article_)` just initialize the `article_` by writing `article_ = ArrayList()` and the error will be gone.

**Cause of Error**

You are encountering this error because You need to initialize the lateinit variable `article_` before using it and you are not doing it.

If you want to check that either the variable is initialized or not then use `::article_.isInitialized`.

**Feel free to ask if something is unclear.**

Answer (score 2):

Change code like this
`binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_test) article_ = ArrayList()`

Answer (score 1):

`lateinit` should only be used when you have a specific reason not to initialize the variable on construction. Here I can see no reason not to make it

```
var article_: List<Article> = listOf()
```

or perhaps

```
val article_: MutableList<Article> = mutableListOf()
```

and guarantee such error can't happen in the first place.